# DATEDIFF and COUNT

Tags: sql, datediff

I would like to count students by their current age for all students registered since 2010.

i.e.

16 - 2
17 - 5
19 - 5

In the current "student" table, I have the student's DOB and registration_date. I am using Management Studio.

So far I have:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM db.student 
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, DOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND registration_date >= '2010-01-01'
```

but am not sure where to go from here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't just use `DATEDIFF(YEAR,...)` to calculate age, since a person that's born December 31 would have 1 year if you calculate the age on January 1st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
select DATEDIFF(Year,DOB,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) age,Count(ID) users from dbo.student  where DatePart(year,registration_date)>=2010
GROUP BY  DATEDIFF(Year,DOB,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need a GROUP BY. Probably something like this?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, DOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), COUNT (*) FROM db.student 
WHERE registration_date >= '2010-01-01'
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(year, DOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact age, you need to take into account years, months and days.

To get a counts of students, grouped by age in years, your code would be:

```
SELECT
   Datediff(yyyy,DOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    +   Case 
            When
            (
                    Datepart(mm,DOB) > Datepart(mm,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                Or  (
                            Datepart(mm,DOB) = Datepart(mm,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                        And Datepart(dd,DOB) > Datepart(dd,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                    )
            )
            Then -1
            Else 0
        End As Age,
   Count(*)
FROM
   db.student 
WHERE
   registration_date >= '2010-01-01'    SELECT
   Datediff(yyyy,DOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    +   Case 
            When
            (
                    Datepart(mm,DOB) > Datepart(mm,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                Or  (
                            Datepart(mm,DOB) = Datepart(mm,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                        And Datepart(dd,DOB) > Datepart(dd,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                    )
            )
            Then -1
            Else 0
        End As Age,
   Count(*)
FROM
   db.student 
WHERE
   registration_date >= '2010-01-01'
GROUP BY
   Datediff(yyyy,DOB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    +   Case 
            When
            (
                    Datepart(mm,DOB) > Datepart(mm,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                Or  (
                            Datepart(mm,DOB) = Datepart(mm,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                        And Datepart(dd,DOB) > Datepart(dd,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                    )
            )
            Then -1
            Else 0
        End
```